# How to play a .m3u file programmatically? (Cocoa, Mac OS X)

Tags: cocoa, macos, file, playback

how can I play a .m3u file programmatically?? Did someone made a class for it? Or do I only need a method?

Please give me a bit of code not only links to websites....

THANK you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

M3U is a playlist format. It is a plain text file containing the locations of music files, most notably MP3 files. Read the [spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U). Then play each MP3 using this if you really want it on an iPhone:

```
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer * musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
     initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
[musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[musicPlayer play];
```

where `backgroundMusicURL` is the location of the MP3 file.

OR

If you want it to play on the Mac, prepare to be annoyed by [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html). I am sure there are wrappers around CoreAudio that make it easy to play an MP3.

Comment: I want to do that on a mac ;)

Comment: my m3u file is an internet radio file. How can I play it?

Comment: should i get the loactions of the stream and play this? But how?

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner Post the entry in your M3U please.

Comment: that's the entry: #EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,SWR3-Livestream
http://swr.ic.llnwd.net/stream/swr_mp3_m_swr3a
#EXTINF:-1,SWR3-Livestream
http://swr.ic.llnwd.net/stream/swr_mp3_m_swr3b